# Reduce array-depth

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array from a key-value table that looks like this (coming straight from the DB):

```
$application_strings = array(
    array('key' => 'building_type', 'value' => 'Building Type'),
    array('key' => 'application', 'value' => 'Application'),
);
/* would print_r like so:
Array(
    [0] => Array([key] => 'building_type', [value] => 'Building Type'),
    [1] => Array([key] => 'application', [value] => 'Application')
)
*/
```

and would like to transform it to something like

```
$strings = array(
    'building_type' => 'Building type',
    'application' => 'Application',);
/* would print_r like so:
Array(
    [building_type] => 'Building Type',
    [application] => 'Application'
)
*/
```

My current approach looks like this:

```
$strings_statement = DB::getDB()->prepare(
    "SELECT `key`, `value` FROM `strings` 
     WHERE `lang` = (SELECT `lang` FROM `sites` WHERE `key`=:key)");
$strings_statement->execute(array(':key' => 12345));
$application_strings = $strings_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$strings = array();
foreach($application_strings as $string) {
    $strings[$string['key']] = $string['value'];
}
```

Can this be done shorter/better?

Comment: A better solution would be to `SELECT` it to output how you want rather than re-arranging the dataset in PHP. Can you show the query?

Comment: If you do a 'print_r($strings, true)' with your method - what do you get?

Comment: Added the query above. If I could modify the query accordingly it would be great. But as I am not too good at SQL, I gave it a first shot with modifying on the PHP-side.

Comment: @ethrbunny: I added the print_r's above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP5.5 the solution is [array_column](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php):

```
$application_strings = [
    [
        'key' => 'building_type',
        'value' => 'Building Type'
    ],
    [
        'key' => 'application',
        'value' => 'Application'
    ],
];  
$output = array_column($application_strings, 'value', 'key');
print_r($output);
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [building_type] => Building Type
    [application] => Application
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$application_strings = array(
  array('key' => 'building_type', 'value' => 'Building Type'),
  array('key' => 'application', 'value' => 'Application'),
);

$output = array();
array_map(function($x) use (&$output) {
     $output[$x['key']] = $x['value']; 
}, array_values($application_strings));
```

Was the solution I came up with if you don't want a loop, similar to Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding other answer, because the first one used array_map to transform the current array, but this is not to just transform the array(I did not catch it the first time), is to convert/merge some kind of Array, into some kind of "Object".

So, array_map is not the faster, the faster function to walk into an Array is array_walk:

```
$application_strings = array(
    array('key' => 'building_type', 'value' => 'Building Type'),
    array('key' => 'application', 'value' => 'Application'),
);
$strings = array();
array_walk ($application_strings, function ($row) use(&$strings) {
  $strings[ $row['key'] ] = $row['value'] ;
}, $strings);
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $strings );
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [building_type] => Building Type
    [application] => Application
)
```

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. I appreciate your adding of another answer after I already accepted the other one. I will look into this tomorrow, as I drop the hammer soon.

Comment: I ended up with two similar situations. In each of them, one of your answers fitted better. So I will keep the answer given first marked as accepted...

Answer (score 0):

This is an Array map, try this:

```
$application_strings = array(
    array('key' => 'building_type', 'value' => 'Building Type'),
    array('key' => 'application', 'value' => 'Application'),
);
function transform($row){
  return array( $row['key'] => $row['value'] );
}
$strings = array_map ('transform', $application_strings);
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $strings );
echo '</pre>';
```

This gives

```
Array(
    [0] => Array([building_type] => 'Building type'),
    [1] => Array([application] => 'Application')
)
```

Comment: This makes sorts key and value right, but gives me the same level of nesting. So I go for Martins answer.

Comment: You ask for short or better way to do it. It is not shorter but is better, Loop are for iterate, array_map to transform arrays.

Comment: But it does not give the outcome I would like. See my question above for my current approach and the results I need.

Comment: I got the issue that you mean in your edited comment regarding the nested.